# NSString to PDF file - Format contents

Tags: pdf, nsstring, formatting

I want to write several fields which are present in my iPad application to a PDF file.

e.g.
First Name, Last Name, Date of birth, Emplyoment Date, Employer, Address, etc...

I am able to capture all the fields in one of the NSString (I am appending each fields separated by new line \r\n).

But when the content is written to file, it is not proper.

Is it possible to somehow capture all the Titles and their values in a columns and write the same to PDF file?

regards,

Nirav